# MongoDB pipeline aggregation adding values together

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I want to use pipeline aggregation in MongoDB to query certain values from documents and then add them together.

My "Albums" document.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5875ed1dc939408da0601f31"),
"AlbumName" : "Blurryface",
"Artist" : "21 Pilots",
"Date" : "20151110",
"Label" : "Fueled By Ramen",
"Writers" : "Tyler Joseph",
"Producer" : "Mike Elizondo",
"Songlist" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5875e5e8c939408da0601d73"),
        "SongID" : "1",
        "SongName" : "Stressed Out",
        "Artist" : "21 Pilots",
        "Album" : "Blurryface",
        "Duration:" : "200",
        "nPlays" : 800000000,
        "SongDataFile" : "data"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5875e855c939408da0601dcc"),
        "SongID" : "4",
        "SongName" : "Heathens",
        "Artist" : "21 Pilots",
        "Album" : "Blurryface",
        "Colaborator" : "NA",
        "Duration:" : "320",
        "nPlays" : 5000000,
        "SongDataFile" : "data"
    }
]
}
```

How can I make an aggregation pipeline that extracts the "nPlays" from the songs in the array and then add them together?

I'm asking here since the documentation on MongoDB is subpar and they have no examples of how to use the operators together. Add to this that all examples on google only query for $gt $lt or use the same example that only uses $match and $group which doesn't help me with my problem at all.

In short:

How do I extract "nPlays" and add them together in a pipeline aggregation?

Comment: What's your MongoDB version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to *unwind* the internal documents. This operation creates a document for each subdocument in `Songlist` field.

The resulting aggregation pipeline is the following:

```
db.Albums.aggregate([
  {$unwind: {path: "$Songlist"}},
  {$project : { "_id" : 0, "AlbumName" : 1, "Songlist.nPlays" : 1} },
  {$group : {"_id" : "$AlbumName", "sum" : {"$sum" : "$Songlist.nPlays"}}}
])
```

The result document is this:

```
{
  "_id" : "Blurryface",
  "sum" : 805000000
}
```

In summary, with the `$unwind` operation you *flatten* inner subdocuments. Then, with a simple `$project` you can retain only the fields you need (this stage is optional). Finally, using a `$group`, you can sum over the information you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, alright. I knew about the $unwind, but i didn't know that you could use $group and then $sum on a specified group attribute. Thank you very much!

Comment: Follow up question if you have time. Say i have many albums in my collection "Albums". How do I then group the total nPlays for each album and compare that, and then $limit to the most played album? (Which album has greatest nTotalPlays?

Comment: Yeah, silly me. I tried adding another album, it does indeed! Sorry for asking so many other questions, but how do I then limit the result set to only one result. (The biggest). I know that I should use $limit, but what syntax do I use at the end after $group?

Answer (score 3):

For the most efficient solution which does not need multiple pipelines, I would suggest bumping your MongoDB server to 3.4 (if using earlier versions), and use the new **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce)** array operator to add the fields' values in the `Songlist` array in a seamless manner.

It calculates the sum of the `"Songlist.nPlays"` fields in the array by applying an expression to each element in an array and combining them into a single value.

You can then use this as an expression with the **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** pipeline to get the desired field along with the other fields:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$addFields": { 
            "totalPlayDuration": {
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$Songlist",
                    "initialValue": 0,
                    "in": { "$add": ["$$value", "$$this.nPlays"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }           
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5875ed1dc939408da0601f31"),
    "AlbumName" : "Blurryface",
    "Artist" : "21 Pilots",
    "Date" : "20151110",
    "Label" : "Fueled By Ramen",
    "Writers" : "Tyler Joseph",
    "Producer" : "Mike Elizondo",
    "Songlist" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5875e5e8c939408da0601d73"),
            "SongID" : "1",
            "SongName" : "Stressed Out",
            "Artist" : "21 Pilots",
            "Album" : "Blurryface",
            "Duration:" : "200",
            "nPlays" : 800000000,
            "SongDataFile" : "data"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5875e855c939408da0601dcc"),
            "SongID" : "4",
            "SongName" : "Heathens",
            "Artist" : "21 Pilots",
            "Album" : "Blurryface",
            "Colaborator" : "NA",
            "Duration:" : "320",
            "nPlays" : 5000000,
            "SongDataFile" : "data"
        }
    ],
    "totalPlayDuration": 805000000
}
```

---

**NB**:
A solution that uses **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** may not be as efficient at scale and expect drop in performance when dealing with large arrays because it produces a cartesian product of the documents i.e. a copy of each document per array entry, which uses more memory (possible memory cap on aggregation pipelines of 10% total memory) and therefore takes time to produce as well processing the documents during the flattening process.

Also, a multiple pipeline solution requires knowledge of the document fields since this is needed in the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline where you retain the fields in the grouping process by using the accumulators like **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)**. That can be a huge limitation if your query needs to be dynamic. So in essence it would be more beneficial to take advantage of the new operators found in MongoDB versions 3.4 and above which offer improved aggregation pipeline performance.

Comment: imho you're not giving a solution to the original use case. All the information you gave are extremely usefull and correct, but they are not the answer to the original question.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The OP's question is _How can I make an aggregation pipeline that extracts the "nPlays" from the songs in the array and then add them together?_ and the above answer addresses that through the use of `$reduce` which extracts the `nPlays` field without the need for `$unwind` which can be expensive computationally given large arrays. Now I am not sure how this answer doesn't fit/solve the OP's question as you imply, care to show me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate with $group. This will give total for all records.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
   {$unwind: '$Songlist'},
    {$group: {_id: null, sum: {$sum: '$Songlist.nPlays'}}}
])
```